# Kafka Broker failover handling in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, failover

## Overview

We have 3 Brokers running in a cluster, addresses of brokers are:

```
localhost:9091, localhost:9092, localhost:9093
```

1 Zookeeper is running at : `localhost:8081`

We have configured 1 Consumer in Spring boot with bootstrap address as below:

```
bootstrapAddress=localhost:9091,localhost:9092,localhost:9093
```

## Problem

Everything works fine when all the Kafka servers are up and running. The message gets published correctly and gets consumed correctly.
*But when any one of the above Kafka Server stops running*, the spring boot application shows the message as below:

```
[WARN ] NetworkClient:671 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=demo] 
   Connection to node 3 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

And then the boot application (i.e. the consumer), stops consuming the messages pushed to kafka after that.

I have checked through Kafka commands that the new Leader is getting elected correctly. And the messages are being pushed correctly after the new leader election. But due to stalling of the boot application, the message is not getting consumed.
Also, as soon as the Kafka server is started, the message consumption goes back to normal. Even the messages published when the spring boot service was stalled, gets consumed correctly without any restart of the boot jar.

**So, is there a way to configure the Kafka Consumer in spring boot such that it does not stalls even if any/all brokers have stopped working?**

## Configurations

Configuration of Topic:

```
Number of partitions = 3
Number of replicas = 3
```

Spring Kafka Version : `2.2.7.RELEASE`
Kafka Version : `2.12-2.3.0`

Code to configure the consumer

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfiguration
{
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, CaseActivityDTO> consumerFactory()
{
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(getConsumerConfigurations());
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, CaseActivityDTO>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory()
{
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, CaseActivityDTO> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(3));
    return factory;
}

private Map<String, Object> getConsumerConfigurations()
{
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9091,localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, autoCommitInterval);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, retryBackoff);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollInterval);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}
}
```

.

```
package demo.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Service
public class ConsumerService
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerService.class);

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @KafkaListener(id = "demoId", topics = "demo", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenCaseActivity(@Payload String payload)
    {
        try
        {
            LOGGER.info("Payload:{}",payload);
        }
        catch (IOException | RuntimeException e)
        {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are log.dirs for all brokers?

Comment: Any specific reason using Spring Kafka? You can use plain kafka-clients in Spring boot.

Comment: @AshishBhosle We have different log.dir for each broker.    

    
{Kafka Logs main folder}/kafka-log1    
{Kafka Logs main folder}/kafka-log2    
{Kafka Logs main folder}/kafka-log3

Comment: @AshishBhosle Reason for using Spring Kafka is that it needs very less configuration when using in a Spring Boot Application. It provides almost all the things which are required by us and the amount of code that needs to be writeen is very less compared to using the kafka-clients directly.

Comment: Understood. I also use Spring boot, but do not use Spring Kafka, so I need to try this one. If you some time, try plain Kafka and see.

Comment: @AshishBhosle Sure will try that

Comment: Hello. Did you resolve this problem?